# Paramiko: passing a dict as argument to connect

Tags: python, paramiko

I have the following call which works (actually raises a `paramiko.AuthenticationException`, which is fine):

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('example.com',username='root', password="aaa", look_for_keys=False, timeout=5)
```

I wanted to convert the parameters into a dict:

```
params = {
    'hostname': 'example.com',
    'port': 22,
    'username': 'root',
    'look_for_keys': False,
    'timeout': 5
    }
ssh.connect(params)
```

This raises a `TypeError: getaddrinfo() argument 1 must be string or None`. I checked the arguments to `ssh.connect`

```
>>> inspect.getargspec(ssh.connect)
ArgSpec(args=['self', 'hostname', 'port', 'username', 'password', 'pkey', 'key_filename', 'timeout', 'allow_agent', 'look_for_keys', 'compress', 'sock'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=(22, None, None, None, None, None, True, True, False, None))
```

and my dict looks good to me.

Nevertheless, since the first call is fine and the error is socket related I tried

```
ssh.connect('example.com', 22, params)
```

which raises `paramiko.SSHException: No authentication methods available`. I interpret this as `connect` not having any password or key to test.

What should I do so that `ssh.connect` accepts a dict as parameter (or actually - how different should the dict be compared to mine)?

Or is there another pythonic way to pass parameters, short of building the parameters string "manually" (by concatenating strings, which looks awful to me)?

Comment: Is the signature compatible so that `ssh.connect('example.com', 22, **params)` works ?

Comment: I tried `(**params)` and it worked out of the box. Thanks a lot. Would you mind turning your comment into an answer so that I can accept it? Also: what do you mean by "signature compatible"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dictionary can be "unpacked" and be used as though keyword arguments had been declared explicitly by using `**` in the function call, eg:

```
ssh.connect('example.com', 22, **params)
```

You just have to be careful that position arguments are fulfilled and not duplicated in the `dict`, eg: the rules for a normal function call...